Using Memory Addresses to Seed Random Numbers in C - Not Recommended?
I'm learning about random number generation in C. While exploring different approaches, I came across the idea of using memory addresses as seeds for random number generators like rand(). However, I'm unsure if this is a good practice.
Here are my questions:
Why is using memory addresses to seed rand() not recommended?
Are there security concerns or limitations associated with this approach?
What are the preferred methods for seeding random number generators in C?
Will it work?
Additional Information:
I understand that rand() is a pseudo-random number generator, but I'm particularly interested in the seeding aspect.
If using memory addresses is discouraged, are there alternative ways to extract some randomness from them for (non-critical) purposes?
I've been working on a basic project to get familiar with random numbers in C, and this question arose while exploring different seeding methods.
here i was trying to get random number with rand()
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int num=1;
    int *ptr;

    ptr = &num;
printf("%u\n",ptr);

int address_holder;
address_holder = ptr;
int random_number = address_holder & 0x000000FF

// int random_number = address_holder % 100
printf("random number ; %u\n");
    return 0;
}

i was expecting a random number to be generated in each time i run the program.
i noticed if i use %u for printing address it results in memory address being printed i numbers
result: was failure ,so far i cant store that printed value of pointer using %u .

Addresses can be consistent between runs. Better to use the current time for seeding.

@adityaT-7, avoid mixing print specifiers and type.  Use "%u" with unsigned and "%p" with void * . (printf("%p\n",(void *) ptr);),  Save time and enable all compiler warnings.

Some platforms use address space layout randomization to set up parts of a program’s memory. Since they are attempting to thwart an attacker, they ought to be using a good source of random numbers for this. However, the amount of randomization they can do is limited. Typically, they must maintain page alignment, so the low bits of addresses never change. And the amount of variation in the high bits may be limited by various platform requirements. So an address might not provide as much randomization as you would like. It may be okay for casual purposes. But not much more.

@wohlstad Better to use the current time for seeding. Note, though, that if someone knows when the process was run they have a relatively small number of possible seeds to try if they want to recreate your "random" values.

In addition to what has already been said: If you intent to use the random numbers for anything close to a cryptographic or scientific use case, then of course rand and any of the mentioned seeding methods are really really bad. Scientific use cases need much better PRNG algorithms and usually use fixed seed values for reproducibility. Cryptographic use cases need special kinds of PRNG and must be seeded with actual random values, usually provided form hardware sources.

" i noticed if i use %u for printing address it results in memory address being printed i numbers result: was failure ,so far i cant store that printed value of pointer using %u ."  I cannot understand that sentence at all.  Can you please rephrase?  (If it's relevant: did you notice that your current test program doesn't actually pass an argument to printf? As chux said, compiler warnings would catch that.)

Addresses may be randomized by the operating system in order to make exploitation of certain bugs more difficult. However, there are many reasons to avoid using address randomness to seed any RNG, even non-critical ones:

Randomization may not be applied in certain circumstances. For example, a program compiled without PIE (Position Independent Executable) will always be loaded at a fixed address. Programs running with randomization disabled (e.g. under a debugger) will always load at predictable addresses.
The amount of randomization actually applied varies widely. On many versions of Windows, for example, addresses are randomized once per boot, and are therefore consistent until you reboot the machine. On Linux, addresses can have as little as 20 bits of entropy (less even on 32-bit systems), particularly since the final 12 bits are not randomized for most segments.
Using addresses to seed an RNG makes your program’s observable behaviour depend on the random addresses. Given enough observations of the random outputs, an attacker could reverse engineer the seed and break the ASLR of your program, thus rendering that defense moot. If your program has any memory corruption bugs, you’ve just made the attacker’s job much easier.

For all of these reasons, you should never use address randomness to seed an RNG. Use a high-quality random source, such as the getrandom() system call on Linux or CryptGenRandom on Windows, to generate sufficient entropy for your application; 128 to 256 bits is typically enough to seed a good-quality PRNG.

What functional downside do you see of using the address as part of initialization? E.g.: srand((unsigned)ptr ^ (unsigned) time()) given OP's "trying to get random number with rand()"?

@chux-ReinstateMonica: It seems simply ineffective.  On a system without ASLR, it's no better than simply using time(), which means that running the program twice within the same second will produce identical results.  But I agree it shouldn't make things actively worse.

To remain an effective defense, ASLR addresses need to remain secret. It forces an attacker to find a leak - a bug which discloses memory addresses - in order to exploit some other memory corruption bug. By seeding an RNG with ASLR entropy, you’ve effectively made the ASLR state part of the visible program behaviour; an attacker can use this information to break ASLR and get the leak they want. In short: seeding an RNG with ASLR can effectively disable the ASLR defense.
